# MySQL is ignoring pid file setting in my.cnf on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Another user asked a similar question on a different site. It was recommended he ask here, but I can't find anything on here related to the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431107/pid-file-parameter-being-ignored-in-my-cnf

I am currently experiencing the same issue.

In `my.cnf`, I have set the `pid-file` option in both the `mysqld` and `mysqld_safe` sections to be `/run/mysqld.pid`, but the setting is being ignored, and MySQL is placing the file in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`, as is the default.

I am running MySQL Server 5.7 and Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic). Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

If I run `mysqld --print-defaults`, I see that the config is being read correctly, as I see the following output:

`mysqld would have been started with the following arguments:
... --pid-file=/run/mysqld.pid ...`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18 is using systemd to manage the mysql service.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html

set pid by running `systemctl edit mysql`

`PIDfile=/run/mysqld.pid`

Comment: Unfortunately this produces no change. I used the "systemctl edit mysql" command to bring up the editor, entered "[Service]" and "PIDFile=/run/mysqld.pid" on two lines, restarted the service, and then even rebooted the machine, just in case, but the pid file is still being placed in /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid.

Comment: Although! Interesting... after the reboot, if I try to restart the service, it hangs. After checking the syslog, it seems that attempting to "restart" the service is causing systemd to look in the correct location for the pid file (/run/mysqld.pid) but not find it.

Comment: try creating /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/override.conf and setting service options there.

Comment: Checked and double and triple checked. `:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
PIDFile=/run/mysqld.pid
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS` (Pulled the ExecStart stuff from the MySQL manual link you attached -- tried both with and without it, and with and without the added `$MYSQLD_OPTS`)

Comment: does ` service --status-all ` . list mysql or mysqld

Comment: It lists "mysql"

Comment: systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mysqld
then nothing? or error? or works?

Comment: Fails. Looking in the wrong place for the pid file. From syslog: `Aug  1 21:09:16 ***** mysqld[1286]: Unable to determine if daemon is running: No such file or directory`

Comment: does /run/mysql.pid exist?

Comment: Nope. Never has. Only /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ever has.

Comment: It seems to me that when the service starts, it puts the pid file in the wrong location. But it knows the service is running. Then, when the service stops, it checks for the pid in the *right* location, complains, and stops the service anyway. When it stops, it deletes the pid file that was inappropriately placed. So there are two different places where a pid file is being used, but one is accepting and the other is refusing the setting in `override.conf`.

Comment: make sure all mysql processes are stopped.  touch /run/mysql.pid.   give it the same permissions and ownership as /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid.  then I'm out of ideas without a better picture.

Comment: Done. Same error. Very confused. Crying. Thinking of giving up :(